# RNMapbox/maps: Impossible to load a style on Android

Tags: android, react-native, mapbox, mapbox-android

I try to make my first application with the library RNMapbox/maps, everything is working fine on iOS but on android, I have this error:

```
Mapbox error [HTTP] Unable to parse resourceUrl mapbox://styles/magnasie/cl0ifyl63000z14o5o993xd2o {"level": "error", "message": "[HTTP] Unable to parse resourceUrl mapbox://styles/magnasie/cl0ifyl63000z14o5o993xd2o", "tag": "Mbgl-HttpRequest"}
```

I think it's because maplibre is by default and can't access to Mapbox style ? But I'm not sure. And when I want to set Mapbox v10 in build.gradle, I have this error:
[image]

Followed by this one on build:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.


Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.mapbox.maps:android:10.3.0.
```

When I search on google, it seems that I try to sync on offline mode, but no, my Gradle is set to online mode.

I try on emulator, but still the same issue.

Thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I correct this issue by doing the second part of this section: [documentation](https://github.com/rnmapbox/maps/blob/main/android/install.md#mapbox-maps-gl-native-sdk-pre-v10)

I was thinking it was only for Mapbox-gl but it seems that I need it for Mapbox, Maplibre and Mapbox-gl

Answer (score 0):

You either needs to set RNMapboxImpl to `mapbox` in pod/gradlefile to use mapbox (v10) implementation.

If you want to use Mapbox styles with maplibre implementation you need to use [Mapbox.setWellknownTileServer(Mapbox.TileServers.Mapbox)](https://github.com/rnmapbox/maps/blob/main/docs/MapboxGL.md#setwellknowntileservertileserver)